# cakephp how to use call back method

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am new to cakephp. I am trying to put a query in after getting the result part in model and use it in call back. But getting errors when I try to get the debug of $newArray from model.. In my controller I have this

```
function index($var = null){


             if (empty($this->data)) {




             } 
             else { 


                            $results = array();

                            $getRecords = $this->Model->find('all');
                                $results = $this->Model->afterFind($getRecords);
                                debug($this->newArray);

            }
    }
```

In my Model I have this

```
class Model extends AppModel {
function afterFind($getRecords){
    $newArray = array();    
    $query_string = $getRecords['Record']['column1']" ;
    $results = $this->Model->query($query_string);
        foreach($results as $result){


        //do something and add to $newArray

        }
        return $newArray;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callbacks are automatically called by Cake, you do not call them by hand (that's the point, otherwise they'd be normal methods). The flow is:

- Controller calls `Model::find`
- Cake triggers `Model::beforeFind` callback, if present
- Cake finds results
- Cake triggers `Model::afterFind` callback if present, passing in an array of found data

  - the callback is supposed to return data
- Controller receives the data returned by `Model::afterFind`

There are examples for `afterFind` [in the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1050/afterFind). You should not trigger further queries from `afterFind`, as this may go into an infinite loop, with each query triggering more `afterFind` callbacks. I also wouldn't suggest to alter your results too drastically in an `afterFind`, you should only do light massaging of the results where necessary. I can't tell from your post what it is you're trying to achieve, so I can't give any concrete hints, but you can probably do it without `afterFind` by formulating a better query in the controller.